# how to identify and then update one half of duplicate records

Tags: mysql, oracle

Due to certain issues, my application created two rows for one member in a table. Each member should only have one record in that table. 
Of the 2 rows that were created for each member, the value of certain of the fields are the same, and the value of certain of them are different. Certain of the field values that are identical are supposed to be, certain of them are not:

example:

```
12345   xyz     6789      abc
12345   xyz     6789      abc
```

In the example above, `12345` is not supposed to exist in 2 rows, but `6789` is. `xyz` is not supposed to exist in 2 rows, but `abc` is.

The short way of asking this is, if there are 57,000+ of those rows, and there should only be 28,000+, how do I identify and then change (update) 28,000+ of them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried row contains Numbers X through X show in filter and Numbers X through X show in filter you can edit those two different field?

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a way to identify one of the two rows for each member (it doesn't matter which of the 2 rows I edit of the 2 created for each member), and then have a way to edit the field in the one of 2 rows, for each of the 57,150.Maybe filter would do that best, as you suggest. I'm not familiar with it.